# css causing overflow

Tags: html, css, menu, css-float

**THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ANSWERED**

I have this div which contains two unorderd lists. 
I'm looking to have these lists placed next to each over, not above/below eachother.

This is the best I've come up with, but the lists seem to fly out of the container when the float is added?

Why does this happen? It seems to have something to do with the float, on the UL.

**A little fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/ynSdU/3/

**CSS**

```
.products_overview {width:100%; border: 3px solid #F00;opacity:0.95;height: 50px;}
.products_overview ul{list-style:none;float:left;border-left:1px solid #666;margin:20px 0px 10px 30px;padding:10px;} 
.products_overview li.ldd_heading {font-family: Georgia, serif;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic;color: #333; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;}
.products_overview li.ldd_heading a.link {font-family: Georgia, serif;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic;color:#333;padding:5px 3px 5px 3px; }
.products_overview ul li a{font-family: Arial, serif;font-size:10px;line-height:20px;color:#333;padding:1px 3px;text-decoration:none;}
.products_overview ul li a:hover{-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #333; box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #333;background: #CCC;}
```

**HTML**

THE FOLLOWING CODE IS SURROUNDED BY A DIV WITH THE CLASS: products_overview!!!

```
<ul>
    <li class="ldd_heading"><a class='link'>header</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>                           
</ul>  
<ul>
    <li class="ldd_heading">header</li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>                                  
</ul>
```

Comment: "THE FOLLOWING CODE IS SURROUNDED BY A DIV WITH THE ID: products_overview!!!" Then write that in the code?

Comment: Just change the width to `99%` and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Just give `overflow:hidden` to your parent div

Actually when you use float in your child elements so you should clear those floats so you didn't do that so i am clearing by defining the `overflow:hidden` to your parent div float elements will be clear.

**CSS**

```
.products_overview {width:100%; border: 3px solid #F00;opacity:0.95; overflow:hidden;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ynSdU/4/

Comment: Explorer Mac: hidden

If Explorer Mac is still important to you, use overflow: hidden. This browser always shows scrollbars when you use overflow: auto; and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a clearfix:

I used a `span.clear` to clear your floats.

```
...<li><a href="#">3</a></li>                                  
</ul>
<span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
span.clear
{
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/ynSdU/7/

I prefer to use this method for ease of readability. I can just see the `span.clear` and know that I have cleared my floats. The other methods work just as well. :)

Comment: Can we just add another <div></div> to do the same?

Comment: Yes, you can use a div. I prefer spans because they have no semantic meaning. A div is a Division of a page, because I'm only using the element to clear some fixes it doesn't need to be a division :)

Answer (score 0):

Using floats takes them out of the layout, so they no longer affect the height of the containing div.

All you need is this on your container:

```
.products_overview {overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: Aahhh I can only post every 3 mins because I have less than 125 rep - and in the 3 mins I was waiting, someone else posted first! Haha oh well!